# How do I touch a folder with current time using set last modified date & time?

Tags: java

I'm trying to update the last modified date of a specific folder, here's what I've got:

```
public void touchFolder(){
    File folderToTest = new File("C:\\Temp");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUtc = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatUtc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String newTime = dateFormatUtc.format(new Date());
    folderToTest.setLastModified(Long.parseLong(newTime));
}
```

I am just putting this code in a test case so don't worry about calling this method etc.

I'm getting errors with the parsing that date format as a long, what's the format used in setting the last modified date & time?

Comment: Instead of formatting the date to some string and parsing that to a long (which wouldn't work because `2018-12-19 ...` _is not a long_) just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time as a long.

Comment: Consider using `java.nio` and `java.time` for operations concerning time and the file system.

Comment: last-modified time, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970).[File doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setLastModifiedTime%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime%29), using `java.nio.file.Files`:

```
Path path = ...
FileTime now = FileTime.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Files.setLastModifiedTime(path, now);
```

Comment: `FileTime` can also be done as `FileTime.from(Instance.now());`

Comment: My path was a string so I used this:

`Path path = Paths.get("path\\of\\directory");`

Worked beautifully!

Comment: Tiffany why you accepted this answer and not the ones we added before this one with @Karol Dowbecki?

Comment: @aBnormaLz All are great answers but I am only able to accept one. This one has clear structure with documentation and is quick to implement. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should just do `folderToTest.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Answer (score 5):

In your code `newTime` is a formatted date `2018-12-19 15:21:31` which can't be parsed to `Long`. What you want to do is supply the time in milliseconds e.g.:

```
Date d = new Date();
file.setLastModified(d.getTime());
```

As per [`File.setLastModified()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setLastModified(long)) method javadoc:

> time - The new last-modified time, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970)

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a `new Date()` for this. you can just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @aBnormaLz true, it's just an example of using arbitrary `Date` object instead of current time in case OP has a precise date in mind.

Comment: Oh that's true :)